# The standard article.sty

Tags: latex, styles, document, article, bibtex

> ...the authors should submit the final version as source files, including a word processor file of the text, such as Word or LateX (If using LaTeX, please use the standard `article.sty` as a style file and also send a PDF version of the LaTeX file)...

Please what they mean by the standard `article.sty`, they mean llncs format or which format should I use to write the final version of my paper?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}` is probably meant.

Answer (score 2):

As in the first comment to your question, they mean that you should use the [`article`](https://ctan.org/pkg/article) documentclass if you write in LaTeX. In this case, the first line of your main `.tex` file would be:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
```

with the options (or optional arguments) that you choose, separated by commas, between `[` and `]`.

[Here is the user guide](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/base/classes.pdf) to check the options and other matters but no worries about installation: you'll most likely have it included in your LaTeX distribution.